# Meteor - Iron Router : {{>yield}} is not working

Tags: meteor, iron-router

My problem is that:

1- "{{>yield}}" is not working properly. When I remove "{{>yield}}" from template, then template shows properly. If I place "{{>yield}}" in template, then empty body tag is displayed.

2- If I remove "{{>adlayout}}" from body tag, then empty body tag is displayed.

I have following template code :

```
    <head>
    <title>My Metronic</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
    <meta content="Good Description" name="description"/>
    <meta content="Dave Alex" name="author"/>
    <!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="assets/global/plugins/uniform/css/uniform.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
    <!-- BEGIN THEME STYLES -->
    <link href="assets/global/css/components.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="assets/global/css/plugins.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="assets/admin/layout/css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link id="style_color" href="assets/admin/layout/css/themes/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="assets/admin/layout/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- END THEME STYLES -->

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
</head>


<body>
    {{> adlayout }}
</body>


<template name="adlayout">

    {{> adheader}}
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="page-container">
        {{> adsidebar}}


        <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
        <div class="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="page-content">
                <!-- BEGIN SAMPLE PORTLET CONFIGURATION MODAL FORM-->
                <!-- END SAMPLE PORTLET CONFIGURATION MODAL FORM-->
                <!-- BEGIN STYLE CUSTOMIZER -->
                <!-- END STYLE CUSTOMIZER -->
                <!-- BEGIN PAGE HEADER-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <!-- BEGIN PAGE TITLE & BREADCRUMB-->
                        {{> adbreadcrumb}}
                        <!-- END PAGE TITLE & BREADCRUMB-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END PAGE HEADER-->
                <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        Page content goes here  -  22

                        {{>yield}}


                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END PAGE CONTENT-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END CONTENT -->






    </div>
    {{> adfooter}}


</template>
```

Following is my router settings :

```
    Router.configure({

    layoutTemplate : 'layout'
});


    Router.map(function(){

        this.route('myHello', {
            path: '/mine',
            controller : 'MyHelloController'
        });

    });
```

Following is "MyHelloController" :

```
    MyHelloController = RouteController.extend({

    layoutTemplate: 'adlayout',
    template: 'hello',

    waitOn: function () {
        //return Meteor.subscribe('waitingFor');
    },

    data: function () {
        /*
        data = {waitingFor: 'No wait For'};
        return data;
        */
    },

    onBeforeAction: function () {

    },

    onAfterAction: function () {

    },
    action: function () {
        this.render();
    }


});
```

Can some one guide me what I am doing wrong and how it can be rectified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get more details of whats going on by looking at Chrome's javascript console. You likley have an exception somewhere in your code. The {{>yield}} wont render because of an issue with templates involved in the route you're trying to display.

Its hard to tell given the information you've provided what exactly this error is. It could be an ordinary Js error.

The errors are likely to be in your template's helpers or rendered function (if you have any).

It may also be that your subtemplates aren't rendering properly or have errors in their helpers, such as `adfooter` or `adsidebar`.